# How to get the terminal echo immdietaly in java processbuilder

Tags: terminal

when I create a bash process using processbuilder, I can't get the terminal echo immediately,
I want to get something like [user@localhost ~]$ and the command I flush from the inputstream of the process.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
OutputStream outputStream = process .getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = process .getInputStream();
```

Comment: You can only get what the process sends you and what the input delivers to you. If either of them is line-buffered, you can only get lines.

Comment: When you run a shell on a terminal and enter a command interactively, (1) the shell first outputs a prompt string and (2) the tty driver, not the shell, echoes your input. When you run any program including a shell from `ProcessBuilder` (or older `Runtime.exec`) (1) the shell does NOT output a prompt because it is not reading from a terminal and (2) the input is not echoed because it is not on a terminal. However, you can set bash 'debugging' option `-x` to output the command(s) it _executes_ -- _after_ expanding variables and such, removing redirections and comments, etc.